# The many uses of "if"

Tags: conjunctions

I am wondering about the many uses of "if". These are the ones I know about:

Zero    General truths  Simple present  Simple present
Type 1  A possible condition and its probable result    Simple present  Simple future
Type 2  A hypothetical condition and its probable result    Simple past Present conditional or Present continuous conditional
Type 3  An unreal past condition and its probable result in the past    Past perfect    Perfect conditional
Mixed type  An unreal past condition and its probable result in the present Past perfect    Present contditional

What type of "if" is used in the following sentence:

"If you feel a little bit stiff (doing this yoga exercise) just don’t care about it!"

This doesn´t seem to fit into any category.

Comment: That's a *callous* if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *then* part of an *if-then* doesn't always have to be a result.  It can be used to qualify a command or request for action.

> If the dog is there, then your couch is torn up (Result).
>
> If the dog is there, please take him outside (Request).